# SSO Logout Error

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, logout

Looking at the documentation for the Single Sign On service to logout

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/customizing_apps.html#addinglogouttoapp

I have added the link to logout to my app:

```
https://my-app-1x7de4msey-cl12.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout
```

However when I click on the logout link for the above I get this error:

```
Unable to accept the request to the unknown address, /mtfim/sps/idaas/logout. This is not a problem with the SPS.
```

However that is the exact URL they specify in the documents. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I will try to remember ;)
 `var logoutissuerid = 'https://' + issuer_id + '/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout'; 
 
app.route(sso_logout_uri)
 .all(function(req,res) {
 
 req.logout();
 res.redirect(logoutissuerid);
   
});`
Make sure you grab the `issuer_id` from the login